# Remove this odd mysql account

Tags: mysql

I accidentally hit enter while adding a user into my mysql.  It's entered as:

```
readonly | 192.168.37.196' with grant option;
```

How can I remove it?

I tried:

```
drop user 'readonly'@'192.168.37.196*';
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the name of the user contains whitespace and special characters.

```
DROP USER 'readonly | 192.168.37.196';
```

Might work.

If necessary you can try:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE 'readonly %';
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE user LIKE 'readonly %';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: @ Bill, neither of those removed the odd account.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you sure you have create a user in your mysql? so firstly,i advise you go to the mysql.user to double check if the user is exist. after that using the way provide way by Bill Karwin to remove it